# Javascript: add value to array while looping that will then also be included in the loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

Sorry if this is a dupplicate, can't seem to find it.

```
var a = [1,2,3,4];
a.forEach(function(value){
  if(value == 1) a.push(5);
  console.log(value);
});
```

I wonder if there is a way (any sort of loop or datatype) so that this will ouput 1 2 3 4 5 during the loop (or in any order, as long as all the 5 numbers are in there)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Using `Array.prototype.forEach()` will *not* apply the callback to elements that are appended to, or removed from, the array during execution. From the [specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.18):

> The range of elements processed by **forEach** is set before the first
>   call to *callbackfn*. Elements which are appended to the array after the
>   call to **forEach** begins will not be visited by *callbackfn*.

You can, however, use a standard `for` loop with the conditional checking the current length of the array during each iteration:

```
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if (a[i] == 1) a.push(5);
    console.log(a[i]);
}
```

Comment: @dystroy gotta say, this may be the same code as yours, but it's a much better presented answer ;-)

Comment: true, clear explaination and this is indeed probably the best way to do it. thank you.

Answer (score 9):

Obvious solution :

```
var a = [1,2,3,4];
for (var i=0; i<a.length; i++){
  var value = a[i];
  if(value == 1) a.push(5);
  console.log(value);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you appear to use Harmony, how about a generator like this:

```
function *iter(array) {
    for (var n = 0; n < array.length; n++)
        yield array[n];
}
```

and then

```
var a = [1,2,3,4];

for(var p of iter(a)) {
    if(p == 1) a.push(5)
    console.log(p)
}
```

prints 1 2 3 4 5

Comment: no not harmony. Sorry, forgot to mention. I'm using typescript which is almost like ES6 JS, and any javascript solution will do for me. changed the code example to more normal JS.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a method that uses a callback as apposed to the for loop reduce will work.

```
var a = [1,2,3,4];
var result = a.reduce(function(total, item) { 
    total.push(item);
    if (item === 4) total.push(5);   
    return total;
}, []);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Better</strike> Alternate solution:

```
if (a.indexOf(1) >= 0) a.push(5);
a.forEach( ... );
```

OK, maybe not strictly better, since it traverses the array twice.  However you ought to consider *why* you're trying to modify the array whilst iterating over it in the first place.  It's an unusual situation.

Comment: Note that `indexOf` for arrays requires a shim to work in older browsers. There's one on this page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

Comment: @MattBrowne the OP is using `forEach` and ES6 arrow functions - he has no need for an `indexOf` shim.

Comment: yes it's a bit unusual, but I specifically want to do it within the same loop because it would allow for different tactics in a simple reasoning engine I'm writing, which  then *may* lead to better performance.

Answer (score 0):

SO this is a quick test that seems to work well :

```
var a = [1,2,3,4,5];
a.forEach (function (val,index,array) { 
 if (val == 5) {  
  array.push (6);
 };  
 console.log (val); 
});
```

Comment: Does not work! ...just copy/paste in browser console and test it (I used Chrome Version 63.0)

Answer (score 0):

```
a.forEach(function fn(item, index) {

if (item == 5) {  

  array.push (6);

 };

})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = [1,2,3,4];
Object.keys(a).forEach(idx => {
    if(a[idx]==1) a.push(5);
    console.log(a[idx]);
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

OP here. I've since learned that [ES6 Sets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) *do* include items added during `forEach`.

So *if* you can use a set instead of an array, you can do:

```
var a = new Set([1,2,3,4]);
a.forEach(function(value){
  if(value == 1) a.add(5);
  console.log(value);
});
```

which does indeed log 5 as well.

Just an alternative to the for loop. Of course Sets are different than arrays in several ways, so you'd need to understand the differences and how it effects your other code.