# Why is the output different for foreach and for loop in javaScript for my code as i am pushing new element during each iteration of the loop

Tags: javascript, arrays

As seen there is an array declared as numbers with three elements and variable counter. As in both the loops forEach and for. I am pushing new element to the array in each iteration. To my understanding both the loops should never stop as i am on every iteration increasing the size of the array.For loop behaves as expected and run indefinitely but forEach only prints three elements. i.e 1,2,3. Anyone can help with this.

```
let numbers = [1, 2, 3];
let counter = 0;

numbers.forEach((element) => {
numbers.push(counter + 1);
console.log(element);
});

console.log("After for each");

for (let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
numbers.push(i);
console.log(numbers[i]);
}
```

Comment: `Array.prototype.forEach` caches the array length when started: [`Let len be ? LengthOfArrayLike(O).`, and "Elements which are appended to the array after the call to forEach begins will not be visited by callbackfn"](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.foreach).

Comment: Or this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25243586/javascript-add-value-to-array-while-looping-that-will-then-also-be-included-in